# Adding an Object to a Nested Array in Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to add a new card in the `banking_cards array` inside of the `paymentMethods` array. The `banking_cards` array is inside the `paymentMethods` array. So i wanted to insert the new card object inside the `banking_cards` array. My code below produces an error which says `state.paymentMethods.banking_cards is not iterable`.

**TAKE NOTE**

`banking_cards` array is inside the `paymentMethods` array

```
export const initialState = {
    paymentMethods: [],
  };



  case paymentMethodConstants.ADD_CARD_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      paymentMethods: [
        ...state.paymentMethods,
        banking_cards: [...state.paymentMethods.banking_cards, action.payload],
      ],
    };
```

**JSON**

```
paymentMethods = [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "customer_token": "epofjoe",
    "banking_cards": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "banking_token": "AAA",
        "last_4": "0006",
        "exp_year": 2021,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "cvc": 876
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "banking_token": "BBB",
        "last_4": "0002",
        "exp_year": 2022,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "cvc": 877
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: in the `initialState`, `paymentMethods` is an array but in your reducer function, it's an object? because you have `paymentMethods: {`...

Comment: @tanmay. `paymentMethods` should be an array. `paymentMethods` contains the `banking_cards` which is also an array. I need to add the new card object inside that of `banking_cards`

Comment: Arrays in javascript can't contain string keys...so that `banking_cards` doesn't mean anything. Add the structure you want to achieve.

Comment: @StackedQ. Pls see edited question. As you can see there `banking_cards` is an array inside of `paymentMethods` array. When i want to add a new card it should be inserted inside of the `banking_cards` there.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov. Can you rewrite my code? Thanks

Comment: @Robert Looks like your action is missing what payment method the banking card needs to be added to.

Comment: Does provided JSON is what your `action.payload` look like? If not, what do you pass as an `action.payload`?

Comment: If your `paymentMethods` is supposed to be an array of objects (each having property-array `banking_cards`). If you need to append specific `banking_card` record, you need to indicate somehow ***which exactly*** item of `paymentMethods` you wish to modify (it may be corresponding `id` or whatever else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a card to a payment method your action needs to contain what payment method the card needs to be added to.

Below is a working example of how you could do that:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const createId = ((id) => () => id++)(3);

const initialState = {
  paymentMethods: [
    {
      id: 8,
      banking_cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      banking_cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
//action types
const ADD_CARD_SUCCESS = 'ADD_CARD_SUCCESS';
//action creators
const addCardSuccess = (payementMethodId, card) => ({
  type: ADD_CARD_SUCCESS,
  payload: { payementMethodId, card },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD_CARD_SUCCESS) {
    const { payementMethodId, card } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      paymentMethods: state.paymentMethods.map((method) =>
        method.id === payementMethodId
          ? {
              ...method,
              banking_cards: [
                ...method.banking_cards,
                card,
              ],
            }
          : method
      ),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectPaymentMethods = (state) =>
  state.paymentMethods;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//pure component so not re rendering when nothing changed
const Card = React.memo(function Card({ card }) {
  return <li>card: {card.id}</li>;
});
//pure component so it won't re render when nothing changes
const PaymentMethod = React.memo(function PaymentMethod({
  paymentMethod,
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <li>
      payment method id: {paymentMethod.id}
      <ul>
        {paymentMethod.banking_cards.map((card) => (
          <Card key={card.id} card={card} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            //dispatch action with payment method id
            addCardSuccess(paymentMethod.id, {
              //the new card to be added
              id: createId(),
            })
          )
        }
      >
        Add card
      </button>
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const paymentMethods = useSelector(selectPaymentMethods);
  return (
    <ul>
      {paymentMethods.map((paymentMethod) => (
        <PaymentMethod
          key={paymentMethod.id}
          paymentMethod={paymentMethod}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

With immer I'd use payment method index and not need the map:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { produce } = immer;

const createId = ((id) => () => id++)(3);

const initialState = {
  paymentMethods: [
    {
      id: 8,
      banking_cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      banking_cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
//action types
const ADD_CARD_SUCCESS = 'ADD_CARD_SUCCESS';
//action creators
const addCardSuccess = (index, card) => ({
  type: ADD_CARD_SUCCESS,
  payload: { index, card },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD_CARD_SUCCESS) {
    //lot less hassle using index and immer
    const { index, card } = payload;
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      draft.paymentMethods[index].banking_cards.push(card);
    });
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectPaymentMethods = (state) =>
  state.paymentMethods;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//pure component so not re rendering when nothing changed
const Card = React.memo(function Card({ card }) {
  return <li>card: {card.id}</li>;
});
//pure component so it won't re render when nothing changes
const PaymentMethod = React.memo(function PaymentMethod({
  paymentMethod,
  index,
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <li>
      payment method id: {paymentMethod.id}
      <ul>
        {paymentMethod.banking_cards.map((card) => (
          <Card key={card.id} card={card} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            //dispatch action with payment method index
            addCardSuccess(index, {
              //the new card to be added
              id: createId(),
            })
          )
        }
      >
        Add card
      </button>
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const paymentMethods = useSelector(selectPaymentMethods);
  return (
    <ul>
      {paymentMethods.map((paymentMethod, index) => (
        <PaymentMethod
          key={paymentMethod.id}
          paymentMethod={paymentMethod}
          index={index}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@7.0.5/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Pls remove using immer. Thanks

Comment: @Robert See comment below, you can do `? {...method,banking_cards:[...method.banking_cards,card]}` instead of immer. If immer was a given I'd use payment method index and the reducer would be much simpler (no map needed). Immer is going to be the thing for now as it's included in the [redux template](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#create-a-react-redux-app)

Comment: Thanks. Can you separate code for using immer and not using immer.  Separate them into two files not just comment out so i can better understand. Thank you.